# Adding headers in csv perl

Tags: perl, csv

I need to add headers in to an exsisting CSV file.
i'm new to perl so i've got no clue hwo to do it so if i can get some guidense from yuo awesome ppl it would be.

awesome ^.^

The CSV file layout is as follows.

```
header: name, function, group, 
data:   Henk, Kok,      B,     

header: name, function, group, password
data:   Henk, Kok,      B,   , 1234
```

Comment: You've shown two separate headers. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do something like that:

```
open(FILE,'<',"myfile.csv");
open(NEW_FILE,'>',"myfile.new.csv");
#You header
print NEW_FILE "name, function, group\n";
my $line;
while( $line = <FILE> ) {
    print NEW_FILE $line;
}
close NEW_FILE;
close FILE;
```

From the Perl FAQ :
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to add headers in to an exsisting CSV file

Why not use use this simple one-liner than writing a full fledged program...

```
$ sed -i '1i name, function, group' CSV_FILE_NAME
```

and here is `perl` way of doing it:

```
$ perl -pi -e 'print "name, function, group\n" if $. == 1' CSV_FILE_NAME
```